# Planner does not come out until loaded manually

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Console App won't load up Planners, until you manually open them as that user within the application. This is not desired as this user is automatically added to every O365 group.

Now when I try to run following code, only titles of the Plans I opened at least once in MS Teams or tasks.office.com will show up.

```
var plans = await graphServiceClient
                    .Me
                    .Planner
                    .Plans
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();

foreach (var plan2 in plans)
{
    Console.WriteLine(plan2.Title);
}
```

I have tried to wait for like 30-45 minutes, will try to wait till tomorrow and will let you know the result, but those opened showed up immediately.

Rest of them can be seen on the dashboard of tasks.office.com as they are available, but until I click on them I can't see them in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a different approach to get the plans, which works just fine :-)

```
Task<IPlannerGroupPlansCollectionPage> plans = graphServiceClient.Groups[group2.Id].Planner.Plans.Request().GetAsync();
```